# CSS adjust text side to fit inside a fixed div

Tags: javascript, css, size, font-size, display

I cannot find an answer to this problem.
It seems easy, but I cannot spot a solution even online.

I have a  element with fixed size (100px X 200px),
then I have some text which has variable length,
how do I display the entire text inside the  element without overflowing or changing the  size ?
I'd like the solution to be just a smaller text.

I've tried with "font-size": some vw, but if the text is long It just overflow outside the  element.

Comment: You can't really do something like that and expect it to be a future proof solution. In theory, you could run some js that determines the character count of your string, and then based upon that count you could set the font-size to something super small if you need to force it inside that tiny container. But that's not a good solution. The text needs to overflow for readability.

Comment: You can do this in JS by adding the text to a div which has your required width and noting if it is too tall, if so reducing the font size and adding the text again until it fits. A bit basic but it works.